# npm install bootstrap vs download source code

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap's build tools but I'm having trouble using them when I use `npm install bootstrap`. When I [download the files from their site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/#source-files), I have no problems.

When I install Bootstrap via npm (`npm install bootstrap`) and then run `npm install` inside the bootstrap folder, it looks like it installs, but then none of the commands (like `npm run dist`) work.

When I download the files from the site and then run `npm install` on the folder, I have no problem running the commands.

I noticed that the npm installation includes far fewer files:

[image]

Compared to the downloaded version:

[image]

What am I missing? Was I supposed to install other things separately?

I'm in a mac, with node 8.11.2 and npm 6.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing Bootstrap from their GitHub repository, you get a large amount of files that are only required for debugging, testing, compiling from source, etc. It includes many operations that are only needed if you are trying to **contribute** to Bootstrap.

The NPM version is just a packaged, production-ready version of Bootstrap. Even after running `npm install`, you don't get all of the GitHub files, as they are unnecessary for a production environment. You cannot therefore build the NPM version, except by adding basically everything from the GitHub version.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, but when I try the last step, it says that it could not locate Gemfile... Do I have to make one? Also, I don't know if it matters, but I have to do sudo to install bundler (otherwise it says I don't have enough permissions)

Comment: Sorry - I forgot that the Gemfile isn't added by default. Don't quite know why that's the case. Please see the edit I made (starting with 'Add a `Gemfile`')

Comment: That may fix that issue, but the build folder is not there either, so none of the run commands will work. I just don't see how you can use the build tools if you install via npm...

Comment: Actually, you probably can't build it from the NPM version. Just use the GitHub version if you want to customise, and the NPM version if you want to keep it simple. Please see the changes to my answer. Thanks, and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a better solution... I don't see why they would include the package.json with all those commands you can't run anyway...

Comment: I know, it's a bit strange. Their documentation is also slightly vague as it doesn't specify where you need to download it from.